# Transclusion/include in Sphinx static doc generator?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm writing documentation for a family of products. Some of the sub-sections are identical for some of the different products. I would like to be able to write the text once, and "include" the same text in various pages so I don't interrupt the flow of the reader by having to jump somewhere else and then find their way back.

Bonus points if the included text can take "parameters".

Example document hierarchy and text:

- How to brush your teeth with an adult toothbrush

  `Go to the a drug store and buy an adult toothbrush.
   #include('common', 'adult toothbrush')
   Brush for 3 minutes.`
- How to brush your teeth with a kid toothbrush

  `Ask your parent to go to the drug store and buy a kid toothbrush.
   #include('common', 'kid toothbrush')
   Brush until your parent says you are done.`

Where common is something like:

`Put some toothpaste on your $arg1.`

From what I can tell, this is not built-in functionality. Can it be done with an extension?

Comment: Have you looked at the `include` directive? http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include

Comment: Oops. In spite of having used Sphinx for a long time, I did not know about this! No parameters though.